# span does not firing OnClick inside list react child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components when the parent trigger by OnClick the child which has span element doesn't fire OnClick at all. I try it when the parent is button and it works perfectly but when the parent is list it doesn't trigger the child.

```
class Menu extends Component {
 handleItemClick=(e)=>{
     // whatever ..
 }
 render(){
  return(
   <ul>
     {
       items.map((item, i)=>(
            <li key={i}
                id={i}
                onClick={this.handleItemClick}>
                <Child />
                {item}
            </li>
        ))
     }
   </ul>
  )
}

class Child extends Component {
 handleSpanClick=(e)=>{
     console.log("It works!")
 }
 render(){
  return(
   <span onClick={this.handleSpanClick}></span>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@bunion's answer is correct!

It doesn't trigger your `handleSpanClick()` handler, because the `<span></span>` you are rendering is empty.

Either place some content in it, or either tweak the CSS display property - change it to `block` or `inline-block` and add some `height` and `width`. While developing, you can also set a background color, so you actually see where your `<span></span>` is.

You're code is just fine. Here's a prove, run this snippet:

```js
class Menu extends React.Component {
  handleItemClick=(e)=>{ /* whatever .. */ }
  render() {
    return(
      <ul>
        { this.props.items.map((item, i) => (
          <li key={i} id={i}
            onClick={this.handleItemClick}>
            <Child />
          {item}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  handleSpanClick=(e)=>{ console.log("It works!"); }
  render(){
    return (
      <span onClick={this.handleSpanClick}>
        CLICK ME (I am span)
      </span>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Menu
  items={[
    '-- I am list item, 1',
    '-- I am list item, 2',
    '-- I am list item, 3'
  ]} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
/* So we could see better where it is */
span {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is what i posted an hour ago, good idea with the examples though

Comment: @bunion , your answer is correct. I just edited mine to add credits to you in the beginning :) I was very curious because that was the only reason I could think of too, that's why I added an answer with a code snippet that confirms we're both right.

Comment: Yeah It took me so long to figure it out, Thank you!

Comment: Great! @JimmyJanson , welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that the preferred way of saying thanks around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and [by accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/343165) - clicking the check-mark the most helpful answer to the question you asked (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like its probably because the span defaults to an inline element and if you haven't styled it will have 0 width so it wont have a clickable area. Try putting some text in so it actually has a clickable area to test. If this works style it with CSS (display: block, width, height etc).

Comment: I already tried to add inline style including display: block, width, and height.  It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It has to be empty span because it's supposed to generate css ripple when it triggers by click.

Comment: It turns out that I have problem with css class applied to span. Thanks to your answer I give it another try and it works. Thank YOU @bunion

Comment: Thank @Jalal you for the response, in my case was the CSS too. In particular the span had the following style: 

pointer-events: none;

To the span element I applied the following to fix it:

<span style={{pointerEvents: "all"}}>TEXT</span>